# TBXML While Problem

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

Hey everbody, I'm getting some trouble with TBXML and While. 
I'm trying to parse a couple of nodes of XML. My XML is this:

```
<teste>
```

1
  2
  3

But when I set while, my app just crashes.

```
    itemsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/dev/http/test.xml"]] retain];
 TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

 TBXMLElement * comentarios = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"comentarios" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

 while (comentarios != nil) {
  TBXMLElement * comentario = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"comentario" parentElement:comentarios];

  NSString * descText = [TBXML textForElement:comentario];

  [itemsList addObject:descText];
```

}

What im doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used TBXML but your while loop seems like it will either never execute (if comentarios is nil) or never exit (if comentarios is not nil).  What exactly is the "trouble" you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first child with childElementNamed, and then iterate over the rest via nextSiblingNamed. Here's a convenience method I have written that uses the new block API, might be interesting for you:

```
+(void) iterateSiblingsWithName:(NSString*)name forNodePath:(NSString*)path fromParent:(TBXMLElement*)node withBlock:(TBXMLElementIterator)block
{
    TBXMLElement* element = ( path != nil ) ? [TBXML nodeForPath:path fromParent:node] : node;
    if ( !element )
        {
                return;
        }
        TBXMLElement* valuenode = [TBXML childElementNamed:name parentElement:element];
        if ( !valuenode )
        {
                return;
        }
        do
        {
        block( valuenode );
        }
        while ( valuenode = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:name searchFromElement:valuenode] );
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[itemlist retain];
```

i think it will solve your problem.